# Command line flag to launch Internet Explorer in full screen mode

Tags: command-line, browser, internet-explorer

Is there a commandline flag for IE-8 to launch it from the commandline directly into full screen mode?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`-k` will start Internet Explorer mode in Full Screen mode.

```
iexplore -k
```

Answer (score 3):

For anyone else's information, this actually opens Internet Explorer into "Kiosk" mode, with no way to exit other than hitting Alt + F4.

Full screen mode is different and has no argument from CMD, however, can be configured in Group Policy as follows:

Type regedit in RUN dialog box and press Enter. It'll open Registry Editor.

1. Now go to following key:

   HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Policies\Microsoft\
2. Create a new key Internet Explorer under Microsoft and then create another new key Main under Internet Explorer key. The final key structure would be:

   HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Policies\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main
3. In right-side pane, create a new DWORD AlwaysShowMenus and set its value to 0

PS: Remember we have covered the same Registry key long time back here?

4. Again go to following key:

   HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Policies\Microsoft\Internet Explorer
5. Create a new key Toolbars under Internet Explorer key and then create another new key Restrictions under Toolbars key. The final key structure would be:

   HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Policies\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Toolbars\Restrictions
6. In right-side pane, create 2 new DWORDs NoNavBar and NoCommandBar and set their values to 1

That's it. Close Registry Editor and restart Internet Explorer. Now IE will always open in full screen mode.

If you want to turn full screen mode off in future, delete all 3 DWORDs created in above steps.

Comment: @Jherran, you downvoted because my numbering wasn't accurate? C'mon... that's the solution and you barely edited anything..

Comment: Sorry man, but I didn't downvote you. Just edited. Don't use win, don't know if works, so not me the person you are looking for.